# How to test a method in Junit5

Tags: java, junit5

I have to make a junit test a method in one of my classes, but I never did such a thing and all the info on the INternet is for simple calculation tests. I don't know how to implement a test for my method, to be honest, I tried a boolean check but it did not really help me, maybe someone here can give me a pointer.

I watched a few tutorials with Junit but did not help me out because they are simple methods. I tried a boolean check but I could not make it work

```
public void takeDamage(int damage) {

    if (!todelete) {
        damage = damage / damagereduction;
        currentLife -= damage;
    }
    if (currentLife <= 0) {
        todelete = true;
        return;
    }
    if (currentLife >= 100) {
        sprite.setTexture(skins[0]);
        currentLife = 100;
        return;
    }
    int life = currentLife / 20;
    sprite.setTexture(skins[life]);
}
```

So this method is changing the picture of my character to a set picture depending on the health he has left. I don't know how I could test this method. Maybe someone can give me an pointer.

Comment: Too broad a topic to get into in this forum. You can try looking for examples online.

Answer (score 0):

a simple Test with the information you gave us would similar look like this.

You need to adjust the methods, classnames and actual values you expect.

```java
@Test
public void testDamage() {
  MyPersonClass myPerson = new MyPersonClass();
  myPerson.takeDamage(50);
  int expectedRemainingLife = 80;
  Texture expectedPicture = new Texture(); // You need to load the correct picture here
  assertEquals(expectedRemainingLife, myPerson.getLife());
  assertEquals(expectedPicture, myPerson.getPicture());
}
```

If the Texture is stored somewhere else, you need to get the holding object too, to verify the texture.

Comment: Thanks for answering, Do I have to test the complete Method or can I test one part? I tried to test life only but it gives me an error eventhough the calculation is correct

Comment: Then you know, that something is wrong. That's what a test is for ;) are you returning the correct value in the getter method?

Comment: BTW. This has a name in software development. It's called TDD, test driven development. You create tests first and then start to implement the actual behaviour. Therfore all tests will fail in the beginning.

Comment: The thing is this is for a school project and they told us the tests after we implemented a few things haha. I don't have any getter the value and variables are public (I know not correct style haha). Could the fail happen because I am only testing health and not the whole method?

Comment: This is the error I am getting:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.BufferUtils.newDisposableByteBuffer(I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;

Comment: This error has nothing to do with test, but with the logic of your application you programmed. For this, please open a new question, if you haven't found any answer for this kind of error.